# How to detect F13 - F24 keyboard keys in Blender?

Tags: modifiers, interface, shortcut, customization

Is there a way to access and assign F13 - F24 functions for Blender shortcut keys?
For instance, I would like to assign the F13 key to apply the "mirror" modifier.
I would remap a secondary USB Numpad key (1) to F13 using HIDMacros, but Blender
only recognizes Numpad 1 key on the secondary Usb Keypad.
Here's a [full context](https://blenderartists.org/t/using-blender-with-a-second-usb-numpad/1329724) for this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pie Menu Editor plugin can receive the F13 to F24 keys. Which you can then configure to do almost anything. Build and display pie menus, regular menus, send python commands, you name it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I voted positive on your answer because it is a plugin option.
For anyone else reading:
Use Windows power toys>Keyboard remapping> use F1 to be remapped to F# you need (i.e. F13) and go back to blender, press your physical F1, and Blender will pick up F13. Blender *INTEGRATES* F13-F24 keys natively.